# How to compare cell content with a string in matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, cell

I have an cell array

```
>>D = {'Pop1','Pop2','Pop3','Pop4','Pop5','Pop6'}
```

Now I need an array with result `[0 0 1 0 0 0]`

when I compare elements of D with 'Pop3'.

I tried

```
>> D == 'Pop3'
??? Undefined function or method 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

Can anybody suggest how to do this?

Comment: use the `ismember` function or the `strcmp` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html)

```
>> D = {'Pop1','Pop2','Pop3','Pop4','Pop5','Pop6'}
D = 
    'Pop1'    'Pop2'    'Pop3'    'Pop4'    'Pop5'    'Pop6'
>> strcmp('Pop3', D)
ans =
     0     0     1     0     0     0
```